# How do you know if the elements of a list are odd or even?

Tags: prolog

I wrote two predicates to find out if the elements that make up a prolog list are odd or even but it doesn't work. Why ?

```
odd([X]):- (X mod 2) = 0.
odd([T|Q]):- (T mod 2) = 0, odd(Q).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It did not work because:

- The most important thing: `=` checks for unification. It does not evaluate, meaning that 0 and (X mod 2) can never be made equal. Use `=:=` for comparing arithmetic terms, evaluating both sides, or `is` if only the right side needs to be evaluated.
- You confused even with odd. An odd number modulo 2 should result in 1.
- Additionally: You have no pattern for an empty list. But the second rule already covered the first, so that can just be replaced.

Put together in code:

```
odd([]).
odd([T|Q]):- 1 is (T mod 2), odd(Q).
```

Examples:

```
?- odd([4]).
false.
?- odd([3]).
true.
?- odd([3,5]).
true.
?- odd([3,6]).
false.
```